# Build Qt with ICC fails

Tags: qt, visual-c++, icc

MSVC 2017 15.7 + ICC 18.0 + Qt 5.11.0 (win 10 x64)

Perl Python Ruby are all installed

configure -platform win32-icc -release -opensource

I have tried many times but never succeed.

However, Qt can be compiled statically with ICC, only the shared version can't, I don't know why.

Has anyone ever been successful?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked ICC was not supported by Qt.

Qt's [official platform support page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html) doesn't list ICC as supported to windows. It does list ICC support for linux tho, and only for opensuse.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But there is a folder named "win32-icc" in "mkspecs" folder, I think it means Qt can be compiled with ICC on Windows and I have succeeded in compiling Qt statically with ICC. Only the shared version of Qt can't be compiled. I just want to know why. Maybe compiler bugs?